# IMAP syncronisation problems with google apps (GMail), iPhone and Apple Mail (messages only delivered to one device)

Tags: email, iphone, apple-mail, google-workspace, gmail-imap

We have been successfully using Google Apps for our email in my office for some time now but this week one (just one) of my users has developed a problem I cannot solve.

As far as I can see, no settings have been changed since the email account was set up - I would suspect a change at the google end but no-one else is reporting this issue.

My user has an iPhone 4 and a MacBook Pro running Apple Mail. Both are configured to connect to his email via IMAP.

As of this week, emails are only being delivered to ONE of his devices. For example, if we turn of his phone and I send him an email, it arrives to Apple Mail. Upon restarting the phone, that message will not appear in his phone inbox after re-syncing IMAP folder. Similarly, if the MacBook is disconnected from the network and an email arrives it gets sync'd to the phone inbox but then will not show up in Apple Mail after re-syncing IMAP folders/get new mail.

The messages are present in the inbox though - they can be seen in the google apps/gmail web interface.

I had thought there might be a bug somewhere so the MacBook has been updated to Lion with the latest version of mail and the iPhone as all the latest updates too.

I removed and re-created the mail accounts on both devices and set the mailbox behaviors to get mail and keep things up to date - to no avail.

My user is adamant he didn't change any settings... but as it is isolated to him I am unsure.

That said, I am unsure where to look next - any ideas most appreciated.